# Solidity: TypeError: Member "unbond" not unique after argument-dependent lookup in contract super EthGatedMarket

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ethereum-classic

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Member "unbond" not unique after argument-dependent lookup in contract super EthGatedMarket.
    super.unbond(msg.sender, gatewaySpecifier, quantity);
   ^-----------^
```

EthGatedMarket.sol:

```
///unbond to obtain eth in exchange for gateway tokens
function gatewayUnbond(uint quantity) public payable {

    require(unbondAllow, "unbond not allowed");
    super.unbond(msg.sender, gatewaySpecifier, quantity);
}
```

EthAdapter.sol:

```
function unbond(address payable wallet, bytes32 specifier, uint quantity) internal{

    bondage = BondageInterface(coord.getContract("BONDAGE")); 
    uint issued = bondage.getDotsIssued(address(this), specifier);

    currentCost = CurrentCostInterface(coord.getContract("CURRENT_COST")); 
    uint reserveCost = currentCost._costOfNDots(address(this), specifier, issued + 1 - quantity, quantity - 1);
    FactoryTokenInterface tok = FactoryTokenInterface(curves[specifier]);

    //unbond dots
    bondage.unbond(address(this), specifier, quantity);
    //burn dot backed token
    tok.burnFrom(wallet, quantity);
    //send wallet eth
    wallet.transfer(reserveCost * adapterRate);
}
```

Comment: This isn't enough code to reproduce your issue. Try to make a minimal code snippet that reproduces the issue. (Delete as much code as possible while still getting the error.) Then share that complete, buildable code so we can see the error too.